# react js css styling getting font-awesome icon on same line as Title string

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have been stuck on this for a little bit. I can't get the title and the font-awesome icon on the same line. The title is on the first line and the icon is rendered on the line after it. When I hit F12, I see that the width of the icon is taking up the entire line. I tried adding width but its not working. Here is my code

```
<div className="styles.titleStyle">
  <div className="styles.boldStyle">
    {"MyTitle"}
  </div>
  <div className="iconStyle">
    <i className="fa fa-arrow-right fa-lg"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

in my style code

```
.titleStyle
  display: inline

.iconStyle
  margin: 0px
  padding: 0px
  display: inline
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `display: flex` on `.titleStyle`?

Comment: thanks. that worked

Answer (score 0):

This has, actually, nothing to do with react at all, it's just basic HTML and CSS.

You use `div` elements that have the css style `display: block` by default, it means that every `div` will take the full width available so the next element will start on the next line. If the next element is styled with `display: inline` as your css class `.iconStyle` is, it will still be rendered at the next line after the block element. Long story short, just render the icon after the text

```
<div className="styles.boldStyle">
    {"MyTitle"} <i className="fa fa-arrow-right fa-lg some-other-css-class"></i>
</div>
```

As you can see I have added another css class `some-other-css-class` to the icon, so you can style it as you like.

A bit of in-deep answer and some more errors you made:

`className="styles.boldStyle"` is not valid css class, you probably mean `className={styles.boldStyle}`, this also goes for `className={styles.titleStyle}`.

Fontawesome icons are rendered with `style: inline-block`, it means they will behave like small images in the text and will not break the text flow. The `text-size` css attribute of the outer element will also apply to them. Normally you put the icons before or after the text but not in extra div elements.

Also one tip: if you have a header element, like a title - you should use `<h1>` to `<h5>` depending on the depth of the header, that is basic SEO that does not cost any extra time during development.

All in all you code should look like that:

JS:

```
<div className={styles.titleStyle}>
    {"MyTitle"} <i className="fa fa-arrow-right fa-lg"></i>
</div>
```

Style:

```
.titleStyle
  font-weight: bold
```